# 2. Consider a network 192.168.0.0/24. Specify the 04 subnetworks of the aforementioned network with complete details of each network

Tags: networking

2. Consider a network 192.168.0.0/24.
   Specify the 04 subnetworks of the aforementioned network with complete details of each network

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.site24x7.com/tools/ipv4-subnetcalculator.html

Type in the network and how many subnets you want...